# How can I make searchbar float or stick on screen even while scrolling?

Tags: flutter, sticky

[image: Search bar]

I want both the app bar and the search textbox to stick on screen even while I scroll down

Comment: Can you provide some code of what you currently have?

Comment: try nestedscrollview with sliverappbar setting floating appbar to true.

Comment: I think you would be fine by just using the stack widget

Answer (score 0):

By using bottom property of appbar

```
bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70),
          child: Container(
            //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.90,
            height: 70,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14,horizontal: 20),
            color: Colors.white,
              child: TextFormField(
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                 prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search_rounded,color: Colors.grey,size: 40,),
                   border: InputBorder.none,
                 fillColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
                   enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(
                     color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                   ),borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),),
                   filled: true,
                     focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                           borderSide: BorderSide(
                         color: Colors.grey.shade300
                     )
                 ),hoverColor: Colors.black,
                   
          ),
        ),
      ),'
```